# Iterating through attributes with index in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i add index to iteration on attributes in ruby?

```
<% @child.toys.attributes.each do |attr_name, attr_value| %>
```

I have tried with each_with index:

```
<% @child.toys.attributes.each_with_index do |attr_name, attr_value| %>
```

But where would the index go in?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083570/possible-to-access-the-index-in-a-hash-each-loop

Answer (score 3):

You could do this

```
<% @child.toys.attributes.each_with_index do |(attr_name, attr_value), idx| %>
```

For more details [possible-to-access-the-index-in-a-hash-each-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083570/possible-to-access-the-index-in-a-hash-each-loop)

Answer (score 3):

[`.each_with_index`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) appends the `index` variable:

```
%w(cat dog wombat).each_with_index {|item, index|
  hash[item] = index
}
hash   #=> {"cat"=>0, "dog"=>1, "wombat"=>2}
```

In your example:

```
<% @child.toys.attributes.each_with_index do |key,value,index| %>
    <%= key %>
    <%= value %>
    <%= index %>
<% end %>
```

*Toys* needs to be a member object (attributes won't work on a collection).

-

I also tested with just declaring "key", as follows:

```
<% @child.toys.attributes.each_with_index do |attr,index| %>
   <%= attr[0] %>
   <%= attr[1] %>
   <%= index %>
<% end %>
```

`attr` is returned as an *array* in this instance, where the key/value is used as `0` and `1` elements of the array respectively.